# Can't execute DROP TABLE using php with sqlite3

Tags: php, sqlite, xampp

I'm using xampp to practice sqlite3 and I found that I can't execute the "DROP TABLE" statement using the xampp's built-in php and sqlite3.(But if I use the sqlite3 standalone command line from sqlite's site, it works)

I've checked the return value of exec(), the first line(the 'drop table' one) returns false. And I think it's not the session problem because the second line returns true and execute successfully.

```
$db->exec("drop table ".$_SESSION["cid"].";");
$db->exec("delete from rooms where cid = '".$_SESSION["cid"]."';");
```

and the create one:

```
$db->exec("create table ".$_POST["cid"]."(author text not null, content text, update_time integer not null);");
```

Is there any possible problem I missed?

Comment: It returning true doesn’t mean it’s doing what you think. What exactly is the value from the session?

Comment: One reason for not being able to drop it might be that it doesn't exist. You could use `"SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';"` to test if it is there.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I'm sure it's exist. Even I directly change my code to "drop table test", it can't remove the table called "test"...